# Can this C code which calculates pairs of amicable numbers complexity be better than O(n^2)?

Tags: c

I was trying to print all the different amicable pairs to a certain limit `num`.
i and j are amicable pair if `i == sumProperDivisors(j)` and `j == sumProperDivisors(i)`.
This is my code:

```
void amicable_numbers(int num)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < num; j++)
        {
            if (sum_proper_divisors(i) == j && sum_proper_divisors(j) == i)
                printf("%d, %d", i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working for, but I wonder if there's a more efficient way code which only uses one loop (O(n)). I think that this is possible because we can also check if

```
 i == sumProperDivisors(sumProperDivisors(i))
```

Any suggestions?

I tried the following code:
I tried the following code:

```
void amicable_numbers1(int num)
{
    // Your code:
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (sum_proper_divisors(sum_proper_divisors(i)) == i && i != sum_proper_divisors(i))
                printf("%d, %d\n", i, sum_proper_divisors(i));
    }
}
```

and it gave me this output:

```
220, 284
284, 220
1184, 1210
1210, 1184
2620, 2924
2924, 2620
```

How can I make all the pairs different than eachother so I will get:

```
220, 284
1184, 1210
2620, 2924
```

?

Comment: What does `i == sumProperDvivors(sumProperDivisors(i))` have to do with anything?  And one loop isn't (necessarily) O(n), just as it is possible to have nested loops be O(n).

Comment: Consider moving sum_proper_divisors(i) out of the j loop

Comment: @EvilTeach: Even if `sum_proper_divisors` is O(1), this code is still O(n^2).

Comment: What does sum_proper_divisors do?

Comment: `sumProperDivisors(j)`  or `sum_proper_divisors(j)` ?  Pick one.

Comment: Then I would expect that there is an O(n) loop in sum_proper_divisors as well.   You might be O(n^3)

Comment: Please do not vandalize posts on Stack Overflow; even your own. Content posted on Stack Overflow is licensed under CC By-SA 4.0. Any vandalism edits will be reverted.

Comment: FYI, your current revision from 1 minute ago is asking an off-topic question. Please take some time to review the [tour] and read the [help] pages on what kinds of questions are on-topic here.

Comment: The loops `for(int i; i < num; i++)` and `for (int j; j < num; j++)` have undefined behavior – you can't know how many iterations they will perform.

Comment: Please do not fundamentally change questions after you got an answer (especially not an upvoted one, i.e. one which does make sense to at least some readers).

Comment: What property does do the pairs that get printed that you *don't* want printed share, but the ones you *do* want printed do not?  Hint: There are exactly as many pairs that you *do* want to print as got printed but you *don't* want printed.

Comment: Note: if you save `sum_proper_divisors(i)` in a variable (i.e. `j`), you can avoid re-computing it (twice!).

Answer (score 2):

This *can* be solved by a single loop: for each `i`, there is at most one `j` it could be amicable with, which you already know how to compute; once you have `j`, you know how to verify if they are amicable.

Whether that makes an O(n) algorithm or not (as @EvilTeach points out) depends on the complexity of finding the sum of proper divisors.

Comment: So if you compute the only possible `j` that could be amicable with `i` and it is over the "limit", what does that tell you?

Comment: Hi Scott, does the current revision to the question invalidate this answer? If so, I'll roll the question back to a prior revision. I'm just asking since I don't know C to determine it for myself.

Comment: As you've completely changed what you are asking (from how to *use*  sum of proper divisors to how to *compute* proper divisors), any answers and comments no longer apply.

Comment: (not sure if you meant to post that on the question or if you meant to reference OP instead of me, but it does answer my question, thanks!)

Comment: FWIW I confirm the impression that the edited question cannot possibly be considered equivalent to this answer. Rolling back happened 2 seconds before I would have done it.